# How to configure Ethernet in Gentoo on s390x?

Tags: gentoo

I've booted from SLES 10 SP2 CD and installed Gentoo. Now I'm trying to make Ethernet work (it is working in SLES).
I found [this](http://linuxvm.org/present/SHARE100/S9361uwa.pdf) document, but in current kernel (2.6.38.2) sysfs layout is some different, for example, there is no `parameters` file in qeth device directory, but it have separate file `portname`.

After `echo 0.0.0100,0.0.0101,0.0.0102 > /sys/bus/ccwgroup/drivers/qeth/group` sysfs contains new directory `/sys/devices/qeth/0.0.0100` with few files and directories inside. File `portname` contains "no portname required".
But when I'm trying to write 1 to file `online` it says:

```
-bash: echo: write error: No such device
```

I also tried to write "OSAPORT" to `portname`, 0 and 1 to `layer2` with no success. I still can not create `eth0` interface.

What am I missing and how to corretly make `eth0` configured at boot time in Gentoo?

Comment: Are there any network devices showing up in `ifconfig -a` besides lo?  Also, can you figure out which kernel modules are loaded for Ethernet under SLES with lsmod?

Comment: `ifconfig -a` shows `lo` and `sit0`. IIRC, SLES loads `qdio` and `qeth` modules, and I have both compiled-in on Gentoo.

Comment: I usually recommend using modules for non-critical devices as it's usually easier to debug and test.  For example, if you need to change a modules parameters, however, it appears that none of the s390 network drivers use module parameters.  I'd be curious to see what `find /sys -name '*eth*'` and `dmesg | grep -E '(qdio|qeth)'` reveals under both Gentoo and SLES.

Comment: Have you tried booting from a Gentoo live cd? If so, did you execute net-setup?

Comment: I've not found live-cd for s390x, only stage3 tarball.

Comment: I suppose that you already follow the procedure described [here](http://dev.gentoo.org/~vapier/s390/) in the "Networking Configuration" chapter. What was the result?

Comment: No result at all. I've created file `/etc/ccwgroup.conf`, but `eth0` still not created and `grep -R 'ccwgroup\.conf' /etc/init.d` shows nothing.

Comment: I think you have more luck using the gentoo email lists. S390 is not very common and it seems your problem is specific to it.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, "`-bash: echo: write error: No such device`" usually means there is no kernel support for a given device. So you should try to reconfigure and rebuild your kernel. If you can find any other working kernel (e.g. from SLES), its config will be the best starting point.